# Does DJI Mobile App iOS SDK give access to all the features available in DJI GO App?

Tags: dji-sdk

I have an app that captures photos, add some additional details and send the images to my server that is currently used in an enterprise setup. I would like to add DJI Framework so the images captures thru the drone (thinking of Phantom 3) go thru the same workflow.

I DO NOT want the user to use 2 different apps (DJI GO to control the drone and capture photos) and our custom app to (import from DJI) and upload the photos to server. Would rather have everything as part of my custom App.

Answer (score 1):

In the DJI SDK, most of the features are supported in the framework. Also, there is a sample app which is involved in the framework. I suggest to go through the code and find out which feature you want to use and implement in your app. Technically, you could implement you own 'DJI Go App' except some of features which require respond from DJI Sever.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make custom image manipulation after recording the images from DJI drone 
Following are the steps you have to consider for the app

1. Use DJI SDK for image capture
2. After capturing the image is finished then manipulate the images using OpenCV framework.
3. Post the data to server

You can also follow tutorial provided by them:
https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/PanoDemo.html